# argumentparser close file argument

Tags: python

argumentparser can take file type argument and leave the file open directly, for example:

```
parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args().__dict__
input = args['infile'].readlines()
```

do I need to close `args['infile']` in my program? Would argumentparser close it for me? I didn't find anywhere mention this in the documentations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO, it does not close the filetype object.. see [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue13824)

The problem here is that `FileType` may return `stdin` or `stdout`, so it can’t just always close the file object.

A great number of unclosed file handles may cause problem to some OSes, but that’s it.  On the plus side, the fact that argparse accepts for its type argument any callable that can check and convert a string input is simple, clean and works.

Also look at [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2012-February/158650.html)

Comment: So, since argparse doesn't close the file, wouldn't it simply be better to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863004/1903852

Answer (score 1):

Some digging in the [source](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/argparse.py) reveals that it doesn't close it for you. That makes sense, as it also has to open files for writing, and you probably wouldn't want it to close those.

Comment: I wouldn't want to close that even after writing?

Comment: You'd want to close it _yourself_, but you wouldn't want argparse to close it, because then it would be closed immediately, before you had a chance to use it--which would make it pointless for argparse to have opened it to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have stumbled onto a clear and concise way to close `argparse` files:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Hello!')
parser.add_argument('src_file', 
    type=argparse.FileType('r', encoding='Windows-1252'), help='Input .txt file')
parser.add_argument('dst_file', 
    type=argparse.FileType('w', encoding='Windows-1252'), help='Output .foo file')
args = parser.parse_args()
# do your thing...
args.src_file.close()
args.dst_file.close()
#close(args.src_file)  don't do this... gives error
```

This is with Python 3.10.4; googling the PEPs for this 'feature', nothing was found.

So either this:

- Has existed all along but nobody knew,
- Was added at some point but not mentioned,
- Or it doesn't actually close the file (and doesn't give any error.)*

*The Python debugger in Code/Win10 reports the `<_io.TextIOWrapper>`'s `closed` boolean does change to `True` from this `.close()`, so it *seems* to be working as expected.