# Is a Python File object a real file?

Tags: python, file-io

In Python a file object may point to a real file, stdin, stdout, stderr, or even something else. So it can be **file-like**, or a **real file** as stated on [file.flush](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush).

How to know if a file is a real file? I found some ways to guess but none seems really reliable:

1. `file not in [sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr]` -- Seems safest but only for those standard types, not very generic solution.
2. `os.path.isfile(file.name)` -- Seems pretty safe but might not work if new file is opened in some creation modes I guess.
3. `file.fileno() == 0` -- This supposes the method isn't implemented, default implementation returns 0, and normal implementations never return 0.
4. `file.name.startswith('<')` -- This really supposes the file system doesn't allow `<` in the file name.

Why I need to know this, is because I'd like to close it early and using `with file as f:` may close stdin/stdout which sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: This is quite tricky because one could write a file-like object class that passes all your tests, while still not actually pointing to a real file. Ex. My `FakeFile` class could have a `name` attribute pointing to an existing file, it could override `fileno` to return 0, etc. It seems like a sufficiently determined coder could foil your every attempt.

Comment: In any case, your usage of `with` seems strange to me. Most of the time, I see it used like `with open(filename) as f:`, which eliminates the possibility that `f` could point to stdin/out/err.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you should use the `with ... as f:` only symmetrically, that is, with file handles that you `open` or acquire in the `with` statement.

---

On UNIX you can check `.fileno()` - 0 stands for standard in, 1 for standard out and 2 for standard error; generally you shouldn't close these streams, as there is really no way to reopen them anymore.

---

`file.name` is not really 100 % proof approach, since many streams can have a name, even though they are not real files, and that special name can clash with an existing file on the disk:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.exists(sys.stdin.name)
True
>>> sys.stdin.name
'<stdin>'
```

(hint, just moments before I did `touch '<stdin>'`)

Also, in UNIX it is customary to unlink temporary files right after opening them, so they do not *exist* any more by that name; on the other hand even an existing file may be *renamed* after it is opened, and thus does not exist by the original name.

---

If you want to find out if a standard stream is redirected to a file, you can do:

```
>>> import os
>>> import stat   
>>> stat.S_ISREG(os.fstat(sys.stdout.fileno()).st_mode)
False
```

`S_ISREG` returns `True` if the mode describes an ordinary file (here the output goes to terminal so it is False); likewise you can find out if any file is redirected to a *terminal* with `isatty`:

```
>>> os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno())
True
```

Comment: Your first remark is true, yet `argparse` for example gives you directly an opened file pointer.

Answer (score 0):

[This part](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fbc7723778be01b8f3bb72d2dcac15ab9fbb9923/Lib/socket.py#L349-L356) from Python's socket library may be helpful (where `file` is a file object):

```
    try:
        fileno = file.fileno()
    except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation) as err:
        raise _GiveupOnSendfile(err)  # not a regular file
    try:
        fsize = os.fstat(fileno).st_size
    except OSError as err:
        raise _GiveupOnSendfile(err)  # not a regular file
```