# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 's': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://s?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, request, subdomain

i am working on subdomain chacker that test url's from file and print worcking one's first i used urllib not dowing the job
saw i use requets and every thing work will bat
i have error with the reqeust
example of url:

```
https://et7-1.fab5-2-gdc.bf1.yahoo.com
```

my code

```
import argparse, requests
from requests.exceptions import MissingSchema
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-f", "--file",required=True, help="subdomain file" )
args = p.parse_args()
def get_url_nofollow(url):
    req = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    respnse = req.status_code()
    if respnse == 200:
        return respnse
    

def main():
    url = {}
    for line in args.file:
        line=line.strip()
        if line not in url:
            print('chaching url %d', url)
            url[line] = {'code': get_url_nofollow(line), 'count': 1}
            print("++ %s\n" % str(urls[line]))
        else:
            urls[line]['count'] = urls[line]['count'] + 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

thanks

Comment: `args.file` is a string. `for line in args.file` loops over every character of said string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open file using argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862836/how-to-open-file-using-argparse)

Comment: (The second answer is better)