# how to read a txt passed by command line argument

Tags: python

i want to pass a txt file by command line argument using the argparse module and read the file with `open()` function but first thing i've encountred was this error :

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 's'
```

Here is my code

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My program!", formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("-s", type=argparse.FileType('r'), help="Filename/path to be passed")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
subfile = (open(args.s, "r")).read()
```

Comment: `subfile = (open(args['s'], "r")).read()` ? if `args` is a `dict`, you can't do `args.s` like calling a method `s` from an object `args`. Use the syntax `dict[key]` instead if you want to obtain the value of the key in the dict.

Comment: @MrFuppes thank you for your help but it gave me a type error : TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Comment: seems like you called the script without a filename specified (parameter -s). Added an answer to clarify.

Comment: Why do you do `args = vars(parser.parse_args())` instead of `args = parser.parse_args()`?

Comment: @wjandrea: I guess without calling `vars()`, `args.s` would have worked in the first place

Comment: @MrFuppes Exactly, yeah, that's why I ask

Comment: @MrFuppes yes its true i was giving the wrong file path

Comment: I noted that it it's not possible to `.close()` an io.textwrapper created by `argparse.FileType('r')` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13736862/10197418)). So the code shoud be fine if you just open a few files, but might cause problems if many files. Then it seems to be better to just pass the filename string and open the file in a `with` statement as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863004/10197418).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly read from `args['s']`, since `type=argparse.FileType('r')`. No `open()` needed:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My program!", formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("-s", type=argparse.FileType('r'), help="Filename/path to be passed")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
data = args['s'].readlines()
print(data)
```

now you can call the script from the command prompt, e.g. as `python .\test.py -s'D:/test.txt'` with test.txt containing two lines with letters 'abc':

```py
# prints ['abc\n', 'abc\n']
```

**edit -** you can simplify the code to

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My program!", formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("-f", type=argparse.FileType('r', encoding='UTF-8'), help="path/filename of file to be passed")
data = parser.parse_args().f.readlines()
```

changes:

- changed the parameter name to `f` which I find better-suited for a
  filename input
- added and encoding to `type=argparse.FileType('r')` -
  otherwise, it will take the OS default (e.g. on Windows: cp1252). I'd
  consider it better practice to explicitly specify the encoding.
- directly accessed the `io.TextIOWrapper` with `parser.parse_args().f`
  instead of creating a dict object first with `vars()`

Comment: just a little notice why when i changed the argument to -w and and args to args["w"] it throw a key error

Comment: did you also change parser.add_argument("-s" ... to `parser.add_argument("-w" ...`? btw. I'd use something more intuitive, like -f, for the filepath argument.

Comment: okey i will change it to -f most important it doesnt throw this key error thing

Comment: @toxicpr0xy: you can access the parsed `f` argument directly by calling `parser.parse_args().f` - no need to use `vars()`. Made an edit to clarify. This definitely avoids a `KeyError` ;-) Instead, you will get an `AttributeError` if you try to call an argument that wasn't specified, like here e.g. `c` in `parser.parse_args().c` -> gives `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'c'`

Comment: rules here prevent saying thanks but i cant remain silent with that much of help so thanks so much this is my first script ^^

Comment: Glad I could help! It's fine in the comments I'd say. Anyway, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line:

```
subfile = (open(args.s, "r")).read()
```

with:

```
with open( args['s'] ) as fin :
    subfile = fin.read()
```

Things magically start to work and you don't have an open file hanging around for no particular reason.

Comment: why when i changed the argument to -w and and args to args["w"] it throw :  key error:"w"